# How to get absolute element appearing outside of container with overflow set?

Tags: css, css-position

I have a very small container which has a custom `dropdown element` inside of it.

```css
#main {
  height: 90px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.wrapper-dropdown {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .08em;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #d9e2f6;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #d9e2f6;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}

.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown li {
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper-dropdown .dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6a759e;
  padding: 15px 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9e2f6;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.wrapper-dropdown.active .dropdown {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(217, 226, 246, .8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(217, 226, 246, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(217, 226, 246, .8);
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  CLICK OPTION 1 TO SHOW LIST
  <div class="wrapper-dropdown">
    <span class="selectedtext">Option1</span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#" val="Option1">Option1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" val="Option2">Option2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" val="Option3">Option3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the absolute positioned element (which is the list of options) to appear outside of the bounds of the main container which has `overflow-y` set.

I understand why this happening this due to this answer.

But am simply asking if anyone has any insights/tips/suggestions on a way to get around this or if it's generally not possible without moving the dropdown items outside of the container with the overflow set.

[My example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/ywaxge1k/)

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. You should have your code displayed. Ask specifically where you are having issues.

Comment: Please see http://jsfiddle.net/ywaxge1k/3/ . Why do you set overflow?

Comment: Simply remove `overflow-y: auto`.

Comment: I understand I could easily do that but the height for my container in my real application is only 250px, and I expect to have many dropdown elements within this container. My questions was basically trying to achieve that.